# How to configure JDK logger formatting programatically?

Tags: java, logging

How can I let my JDK logger use my customized formatter implementation without specifying a properties file? I want to set the format by programming.

for example I have my implementation like:

```
My Formatter extends Formatter  {...}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have already built the Formatter implementation, you'll need to bind this to a [Handler instance](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/logging/Handler.html), so that the said handler will apply the formatter when logging the LogRecord objects (after all, that's how [the Logging API was designed](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/util/logging/overview.html#1.1)).

This is done by get a reference to the Handler instance of interest (you'll need to manage the creation of handlers in order to get a reference to them), and then invoking the [setFormatter()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/logging/Handler.html#setFormatter%28java.util.logging.Formatter%29) method on it.